# I dont know how to fix this, any help would be appriciated

Tags: math-mode, formatting

```
\item $\lim_{n \to \infty} L_n$ for $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ over $[0, 1]$ \\
    Known equations: $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}, x_{i-1}^* = (a + i -1)\Delta x$
    \begin{flalign*}
        &\quad \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{i-1}^*)\Delta x\\
        &\text{by definition of left Riemann sum} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{i-1}^*)(\frac{1}{n}) \\
        &\text{by definition $\Delta$ x} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f((i - 1)\frac{1}{n})(\frac{1}{n})\\
        &\text{by definition of $x_{i-1}^*$} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{i - 1}{n})(\frac{1}{n}) \\
        &\text{by algebra} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a(\frac{i - 1}{n})^3 + b(\frac{i - 1}{n})^2 + c(\frac{i - 1}{n}) + d)(\frac{1}{n}) \\
        &\text{by given substitution} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a(\frac{i - 1}{n})^3 + b(\frac{i - 1}{n})^2 + c(\frac{i - 1}{n}) + d) \\
        &\text{by constant multiple rule of sums} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a(\frac{i^3 - 3i^2 + 3i - 1}{n^3}) + b(\frac{i^2 - 2i + 1}{n^2}) + c(\frac{i - 1}{n}) + d) &&\text{by algebra} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a(\frac{i^3 - 3i^2 + 3i - 1}{n^3}) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}b(\frac{i^2 - 2i + 1}{n^2}\\ 
        &+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}c(\frac{i - 1}{n}) +\sum_{k=1}^{n}d) &&\text{by constant sum rule of sums} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{a}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(i^3 - 3i^2 + 3i - 1) \\
        &+ \frac{b}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(i^2 - 2i + 1) \\
        &+ \frac{c}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(i-1) + d\sum_{k=1}^{n}1) &&\text{by constant multiple rule of sums}\\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{a}{n^3}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}i^3 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}-3i^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}3i + \sum_{k=1}^{n}-1)\\
        &+ \frac{b}{n^2}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}i^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}-2i + \sum_{k=1}^{n}1) + \frac{c}{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}i + \sum_{k=1}^{n}-1) +d\sum_{k=1}^{n}1) &&\text{by constant sum rule of sums} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{a}{n^3}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}i^3 + (-3)\sum_{k=1}^{n}i^2 + 3\sum_{k=1}^{n}i + (-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}1)\\ 
        &+ \frac{b}{n^2}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}i^2 + (-2)\sum_{k=1}^{n}i + \sum_{k=1}^{n}1) + \frac{c}{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}i + (-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}1) + d\sum_{k=1}^{n}1) \\
    \end{flalign*}
    \begin{flalign*}
        &\text{by constant multiple rule of sums} \\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{a}{n^3}(\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} + (-3)(\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} + 3(n) + (-1)n) \\
        &+  \frac{b}{n^2}(\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}) + (-2)(n) + n) + \frac{c}{n}(\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} + (-1)(n) + d(n)) &&\text{by known sum values}\\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{a}{n^3}(\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4} - \frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2} + 3n - n) \\
        &+ \frac{b}{n^2}(\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}{6} -2n + n) + \frac{c}{n}(\frac{n^2 + n}{2} -n) + dn) &&\text{by algebra}\\
        \pagebreak
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{a}{n^4}(\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4} - \frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2} + 3n - n) \\ 
        &+ \frac{b}{n^3}(\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}{6} -2n + n) + \frac{c}{n^2}(\frac{n^2 + n}{2} -n) + \frac{dn}{n}) \\
        &\text{by algebra}\\
        &= \lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{an^4 + 2an^3 + an^2}{4n^4} - \frac{2an^3 + 3an^2 + an}{2n^4} \\
        &+ \frac{2an}{n^4} + \frac{2bn^n + 3bn^2 + b}{6n^3} - \frac{bn}{n^3} +
        \frac{cn^2 + cn}{2n^2} - \frac{c}{n} + d) \\
        &\text{by algebra}\\
        &= \frac{a}{4} + \frac{b}{3} + \frac{c}{2} + d \\ 
        &\text{by known limit evaluation}
    \end{flalign*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please state (a) which document class you employ and (b) whether the `\item` directive belongs to an `enumerate` or an `itemize` environment.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't all summations use `i` rather than `k` as the indexing variable?

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` allows you to use a single `align*`-like environment; no need for two separate `flalign*` environments and the `\pagebreak` directive (which don't work anyway, as it's a text-mode rather than a math-mode instruction). I would also change the summation index from `k` to `i`.

In addition, you should use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` sizing directives for most, but not all, instances of `(` and `)`. I'd further recommend using `aligned` environments whenever the expressions require two or more rows.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
\allowdisplaybreaks % <-- allow automatic page breaks in large displays

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
\item Derive $\lim_{n \to \infty} L_n$ for 
     $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ 
     over the interval $[0, 1]$.

    Known equations: 
    \[ 
    \Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}\quad\text{and}\quad
    x_{i-1}^* = (a + i -1)\Delta x\,.
    \]
    Thus
    \begin{align*}
    &\quad \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i-1}^*)\Delta x\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by definition of the left Riemann sum} \\[\jot]
    &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i-1}^*)
       \Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr) \\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by definition of $\Delta x$} \\[\jot]
    &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}
      f\Bigl((i - 1)\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)
       \Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by definition of $x_{i-1}^*$} \\
    &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f
        \Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr)
        \Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr) \\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by algebra} \\[\jot]
    &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}
       \Bigl[a\Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr)^3 + 
             b\Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr)^2 + 
             c\Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr) + 
             d\Bigr ]
       \Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr) \\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by given substitution} \\[\jot]
    &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Bigl[
       a\Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr)^3 + 
       b\Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr)^2 + 
       c\Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr) + 
       d\Bigr] \\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by constant multiple rule of sums} \\[\jot]
    &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Bigl[
       a\Bigl(\frac{i^3 - 3i^2 + 3i - 1}{n^3}\Bigr) + 
       b\Bigl(\frac{i^2 - 2i + 1}{n^2}\Bigr) + 
       c\Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr) + 
       d\Bigr] \\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by algebra} \\[\jot]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigl[
       &\sum_{i=1}^{n}a\Bigl(\frac{i^3 - 3i^2 + 3i - 1}{n^3}\Bigr) 
       +\sum_{i=1}^{n}b\Bigl(\frac{i^2 - 2i + 1}{n^2}\Bigr)\\ 
       {}+&\sum_{i=1}^{n}c\Bigl(\frac{i - 1}{n}\Bigr) 
     + \sum_{i=1}^{n}d\Bigr]
     \end{aligned} \\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by constant sum rule of sums} \\[\jot]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigl[
       \frac{a}{n^3}&\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i^3 - 3i^2 + 3i - 1) 
         + \frac{b}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i^2 - 2i + 1) \\
       {}+\frac{c}{n}&\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i-1) + 
         d\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1)\Bigr] 
       \end{aligned}\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by constant multiple rule of sums}\\[\jot]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigl[
       \frac{a}{n^3}&\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3 + 
                     \sum_{i=1}^{n}-3i^2 + 
                     \sum_{i=1}^{n}3i + 
                     \sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)\Bigr)\\
        {}+\frac{b}{n^2}&\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 + 
                     \sum_{i=1}^{n}-2i + 
                     \sum_{i=1}^{n}(1)\Bigr) 
         +\frac{c}{n} \Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)\Bigr) +
         d\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1) \Bigr] 
       \end{aligned}\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by constant sum rule of sums} \\[\jot]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
        \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigl[
        \frac{a}{n^3}\Bigl(&\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3 
                      + (-3)\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 
                      + 3\sum_{i=1}^{n}i 
                      + (-1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1)\Bigr)\\ 
       {}+\frac{b}{n^2}\Bigl(&\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 
                        + (-2)\sum_{i=1}^{n}i 
                        +     \sum_{i=1}^{n}(1)\Bigr) \\
       {}+\frac{c}{n}\Bigl(&\sum_{i=1}^{n}i 
                      + (-1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1)\Bigr) + 
       d\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1)\Bigr] 
       \end{aligned}\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by constant multiple rule of sums} \\[\jot]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigl[
       \frac{a}{n^3}\Bigl(&\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} 
             + (-3)\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} + 3(n) + (-1)n\Bigr) \\
      {}+\frac{b}{n^2}\Bigl(&\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} + (-2)(n) + n\Bigr) \\
      {}+\frac{c}{n}\Bigl(&\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} + (-1)(n)\Bigr) + d(n)\Bigr] 
      \end{aligned}\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by known sum values}\\[\jot]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\Bigl[
       &\frac{a}{n^3}\Bigl(\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4} 
                         - \frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2} + 3n - n\Bigr) \\
       {}+&\frac{b}{n^2}\Bigl(\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}{6} -2n + n\Bigr) + 
      \frac{c}{n}\Bigl(\frac{n^2 + n}{2} -n\Bigr) + dn\Bigr]
      \end{aligned}\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by algebra}\\[\jot]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \lim_{n \to \infty}\Bigl[
       &\frac{a}{n^4}\Bigl(\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4} 
                         - \frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2} + 3n - n\Bigr) \\ 
      {}+&\frac{b}{n^3}\Bigl(\frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}{6} -2n + n\Bigr) 
        + \frac{c}{n^2}\Bigl(\frac{n^2 + n}{2} -n\Bigr) 
        + \frac{dn}{n} \Bigr] 
      \end{aligned}\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by algebra}\\[\jot]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \lim_{n \to \infty}\Bigl[
       & \frac{an^4 + 2an^3 + an^2}{4n^4} 
        -\frac{2an^3 + 3an^2 + an}{2n^4} 
        +\frac{2an}{n^4}\\
       &+ \frac{2bn^n + 3bn^2 + b}{6n^3} - \frac{bn}{n^3} +
          \frac{cn^2 + cn}{2n^2} - \frac{c}{n} + d\Bigr] 
      \end{aligned}\\
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by algebra}\\[\jot]
    &= \frac{a}{4} + \frac{b}{3} + \frac{c}{2} + d \\ 
    &\text{\hspace{1.3em}by known limit evaluation.}
    \end{align*}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```